# Assigning global var to session variable?

Tags: sessions

I want to assign the user name to a SESSION variable, yet this is not working.

> $_SESSION['loveleytest'] = $user;
>
> $_SESSION['thelovelytest2'] = $user->name;

What should I do?

Comment: I do not see a point in assigning global varaibles to session. You have access to global $user already at every page load.

Answer (score 0):

For assigning user_name to a session variable you would directly do something like

```
global $user;
$_SESSION['thelovelytest2'] = $user->name;
```

I think the issue with your code may be:

1. It is not able to retrieve the `global $user` variable.
2. You might not have defined the global $user variable.
3. Because you did `$_SESSION['loveleytest'] = $user`, thats why the issue is there.

I am also curious to know which was the exact issue.